# Using VBA.Replace and changing workbook name

Tags: excel, vba

I have a file named "3 Entity name - CRF Extract - date month year - PRXXX.xlsm"
I would like to save a code-free copy of the file as "3 (ClientName) - CRF Extract - 02-Aug-2022 - (PRNum).xlsx"
I have the following code:

```
Dim ClientName As String 'then set ClientName equal to a cell value
Dim PRNum As String 'then set PRNum equal to a cell value

ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\3 " & ClientName & " - CRF Extract " & "- " & VBA.Format(VBA.Date, "dd-mmm-yyyy") & " - " & PRNum & VBA.Replace(ThisWorkbook.Name, ".xlsm", ""), FileFormat:=Excel.xlOpenXMLWorkbook
```

And the result gives me this:
"3 (ClientName) - CRF Extract - 02-Aug-2022 - (PRNum)3 Entity name - CRF Extract - date month year - PRXXX.xlsx"

What have I done wrong??

Comment: Do you really need _VBA.Replace( ...)_ at all? You have already build your complete filename.

Comment: Please, try `ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\3 " & "Cliff" & " - CRF Extract " & "- " & VBA.Format(VBA.Date, "dd-mmm-yyyy") & " - " & "PR140.xlsx", FileFormat:=xlWorkbookDefault`

Comment: Thank you FaneDuru but it seems the result is exactly the same

Comment: Thank you Shrotter yes because I couldn't save the file with ".xlsm" directly as an ".xlsx", but it's only because I don't know the right syntax to do it